# How to make divs and other container elements independent of the screen resolution the user is using?

Tags: html

I do not know how resolutions work. If I set the width of my container elements to 1000px and the user opens the page from a 1300px resolution screen, then the right part of the screen 300px would be left white. I don't want that to happen. One way I know is with CSS Media Query but that way I'd have to write tonnes of lines of code. Also I don't want to do it with jQuery. Can someone explain me how resolutions work and how I can create resolution independent elements on my web page?

Comment: Simply don't set widths and let the page flow, or use percentage dimensions.

Comment: what you probably want is `#container { margin: 0 auto; }`. This way the element will always be centered if it has fixed width, no matter what resolution. This element should be direct child of `<body>` element

Answer (score 0):

## Use percentages instead of pixels.

for example

```
div {
height:60%;
width:40%;
}
```

Using percentages instead of pixels will  make it the right size no matter what screen.

Comment: What if I open the web page on my phone, 300px resolution? The width will be 120px, not very readable

Comment: Make a seperate mobile page then, most sites dont work on mobile and desktop without seperate pages anyway.

Comment: Not true, you can make pages desgned to be viewed from PC, but can also view them on mobile by zomming in/out if they're not responsive. Responsive sites are 3rd option